# Язык Си. Помогите пожалуйста, упорядочить строки матрицы по убыванию последнего столбца методом обмена

Tags: c

Я составил матрицу, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы строки упорядочились по убыванию
элементов последнего столбца методом обмена (с флагом). Для меня в принципе метод обмена с флагом незнаком, в интернете не нахожу понятной информации. Кто может, помогите, пожалуйста, что нужно добавить, чтобы строки упорядочились по столбцу.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR argv[])
{
    int  K=0, i=0, j=0, stroki = 0, stolb = 0;
    printf("Vvedite razmernost` matrici (i, j)");
    scanf("%d%d", &stroki, &stolb);
    
    int** A = new int*[stroki];
    for (int i = 0; i < stroki; i++)
        A[i] = new int[stolb];

    for(i=0; i < stroki; i++) //random chisel massiva
        for(j=0; j < stolb; j++)
            A[i][j] = 10+0.001*rand();
    
    for(i = 0; i < stroki; i++) // vivod matrici
    {
        for(j=0; j < stolb; j++)
            printf("%3d " ,A[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    
    K = stolb - 1;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое - `методом обмена (с флагом)`? Ну возьмите сортировку пузырьком - она основана на обменах

Comment: Не прокатывает, учитель говорит, что это немного другое и нужно с флагом, хотя мне везде выдает этот пузырек

Comment: Нужно точно выяснить, что имеет в виду коварный препод. Например, есть разновидность пузырька, использующая на каждом обороте внешнего цикла  флаг, который сигнализирует, были ли обмены и не пора ли закончить. А пока что вопрос довольно абстрактный.

Comment: Поддержу MBo. Алгоритмов сортировки обменом (иначе - перестановками) много. Пузырьковая (Bubble), шейкерная (Shaker/Cocktail), четно-нечетная (Odd-even), расческой(Comb), быстрая (Quick sort) - это всё сортировки перестановками. Какую именно и что значит с флагом нужно использовать - надо уточнить.